# Wireless mouse semi-randomly disconnecting in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-20.04

My wireless mouse semi-randomly disconnects when I don't want it to. It will disconnect for around a second before connecting again.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Using the MX Ergo. The mouse was connected via `blueman-manager`. The mouse is *not* using the dongle

The mouse disonnects when:

- The computer has been left idle for around a minute
- While working and releasing my hand from the mouse for around 15-30 seconds
- Sometimes will randomly drop while I am working only to connect again

Initially I thought that it was something to do with the power settings. I have tried the following solutions

- Setting `UserspaceHID=true` in `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf` and restart the bluetooth service
- Unpairing the mouse. Reconnecting and trusting using `bluetoothctl`
- Adding the following udev rule

  ```
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", ATTR{product}=="MX Ergo", ATTR{power/control}="on"
  ```

This solution did not work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090149/bluetooth-mouse-lags-after-upgrading-to-18-10-cosmic/1090150#1090150

When leaving `bluetoothctl` idle for a while here is the log of it connecting/disconnecting

```
[CHG] Device F2:42:AC:F6:0B:67 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device F2:42:AC:F6:0B:67 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device F2:42:AC:F6:0B:67 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device F2:42:AC:F6:0B:67 Connected: no
[CHG] Device F2:42:AC:F6:0B:67 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device F2:42:AC:F6:0B:67 ServicesResolved: yes
```

Here is the tail of my `journalctl`

```
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                                                                                                                                 [0/1738]
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                               
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)  
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 kernel: input: MX Ergo Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B01D.002D/input/input104
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 kernel: hid-generic 0005:046D:B01D.002D: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v0.22 Mouse [MX Ergo] on 40:ec:99:53:79:2d
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MX Ergo Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.                                                                                                                                                                       
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.                                                                                                                                                              
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MX Ergo Mouse (/dev/input/event17)                                                                                                                                                    
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"                                                                                                                                                         
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MX Ergo Mouse'                                                                                                                                                                      
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event17 13:81 fd 81 paused 0                                                                                                                                                     
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: always reports core events                                                                                                                                                                              
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event17"                                                                                                                                                                                   
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"                                                                                                                                                                                         
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse Trackball                                                                                                                                                         
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: device is a pointer         
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: device removed                                 
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B01D.002D/input/input104/event17"
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MX Ergo Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"                       
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0                      
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000             
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4 
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse Trackball    
Mar 20 12:12:54 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: device is a pointer
Mar 20 12:14:05 box1 systemd-resolved[627]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mar 20 12:14:20 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) config/udev: removing device MX Ergo Mouse
Mar 20 12:14:20 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) Option "fd" "81"                                                                                        
Mar 20 12:14:20 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: device removed     
Mar 20 12:14:20 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"               
Mar 20 12:14:20 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:81                                                               
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 bluetoothd[13084]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 kernel: input: MX Ergo Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B01D.002E/input/input106
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 kernel: hid-generic 0005:046D:B01D.002E: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v0.22 Mouse [MX Ergo] on 40:ec:99:53:79:2d                                                                                                                                               
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MX Ergo Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)                                                                                                                                                     
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.                                                                                                                                                                       
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.                                                                                                                                                              
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MX Ergo Mouse (/dev/input/event17)                                                                                                                                                    
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"                                                                                                                                                         
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MX Ergo Mouse'                                                                                                                                                                      
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event17 13:81 fd 81 paused 0                                                                                                                                                     
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: always reports core events                                                                                                                                                                              
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event17"                                                                                                                                                                                   
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"                                                                                                                                                                                         
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse Trackball                                                                                                                                                         
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: device is a pointer                                                                                                                                                                           
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: device removed                                                                                                                                                                                
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B01D.002E/input/input106/event17"                                                                                                                  
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MX Ergo Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 11)                                                                                                                                              
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"                                                                                                                                                                                     
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0                                                                                                                                                                          
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000                                                                                                                                                                      
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (**) MX Ergo Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4                                                                                                                                                                       
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse Trackball                                                                                                                                                         
Mar 20 12:14:22 box1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1678]: (II) event17 - MX Ergo Mouse: device is a pointer                                                                                                                                                                           
Mar 20 12:15:01 box1 CRON[13606]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Mar 20 12:15:01 box1 CRON[13607]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Comment: I have given up on this and caved buying a wired mouse. This bug breaks mental flow significantly.